# linux progress bar work wrong

Tags: ubuntu-11.10

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and it's progress bar don't work true.

for example when it is copying a file, the progress bar immediatly get full but my file's copy action done some minutes later.

Are there any way to fix this?

Comment: Where is your programming question?

Comment: Where the progress bar is controlling? It have a code!!! and we can fix it to work true.

Comment: If you wrote the program, post the code.  If you didn't, this is off topic for StackOVerflow.

Comment: I am searching around the source that control the progress bars. where can I find this in my OS?

Comment: If it's in the OS code rather than your own, then you are not asking a programming question, you are asking an end user question, and you're asking in the wrong place.

Comment: I want to create a code that interactive with the OS and at first we have to know where that code is and how progress bars are working. So I asked here to complete it's acting and codes.